# Error: network does not support ENS

Tags: json-rpc, testnets, polygon, ens

I am currently trying to build an NFT Marketplace and trying to establish a connection with alchemy-mumbai using JsonRpcProvider. I keep getting this error and can't figure out what i need to do:

[image: Error when running next.js app]

This is my hardhat.config:

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
const fs = require("fs");  // enable file system
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString().trim();
const url = fs.readFileSync(".secret2").toString().trim();
const url2 = fs.readFileSync(".secret3").toString().trim();


 module.exports = {
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      
      accountsBalance: "100000000000000000000000"
    },
    mumbai: {

      url: url,
      accounts: [privateKey],
      
    },
    mainnet: {

      url: url2,
      accounts: [privateKey],
      
    }
  },
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.10",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  },
  paths: {
    sources: "./contracts",
    tests: "./test",
    cache: "./cache",
    artifacts: "./artifacts"
  },
  mocha: {
    timeout: 40000
  }
  
}
```

This is my index.js file:

```
import {ethers} from 'ethers'; //syn front end to backend smart contracts with ethers
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'; //keep track of local state and sustain hook functions
import axios from 'axios';  //axios for data fetching
import Web3Modal from 'Web3Modal'; //support metamask/wallet functionality and connectivity
import { nftAddress, nftMarketAddress } from '../config'; // import addresses for NFTix
//import { MoralisProvider } from "react-moralis";
import NFT from "../artifacts/contracts/NFT.sol/NFT.json";
import Market from "../artifacts/contracts/NFTMarket.sol/NFTMarket.json";



// Application Binary Interface (ABI)
// Application Programming interface (API)

// Server1 => API.json <=Server2    See NFT.json

export default function Home() {

  const [nfts, setNfts] = useState([]);
  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState('not-loaded');
  // require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
  // const fs = require("fs");
  // const url = fs.readFileSync("../secret2").toString().trim();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    loadNFTs();

  }, []);

  //establish a connection with abi with ethers (Web3Modal also possible)
  async function loadNFTs(){  
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/..",);
    const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(nftAddress, NFT.abi, provider);
    const marketContract = new ethers.Contract(nftMarketAddress, Market.abi, provider);

    //return an array of unsold market items
    const data = await marketContract.fetchMarketItems();
```

would really appreciate any tips as to why the mumbai network is not found.

Cheers!

Comment: ENS simply does not work on all networks.

Comment: So to use matic Mumbai I need to use something else other than jsonRPC? How does one approach using the matic network?

Comment: So I am trying to follow this project's https://github.com/dabit3/polygon-ethereum-nextjs-marketplace/. But it still does not work. It seems ENS should work with matic.

Answer (score 5):

[This might be the same problem here](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/1289).
The address that you use might be invalid (e.g. space/numbers accidentally added to address). In this case, your smartcontract address is invalid

Answer (score 4):

I was facing this issue because I was paasing wrong CONTRACT_ADDRESS while creating the contract.

Check that you have passed the correct CONTRACT_ADDRESS

Answer (score 4):

This error can sometimes throw if a contract address you are using contains an erroneous space like so:

`let CONTRACT_ADDRESS = '0x1f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984 ';`

Comment: Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was TypeChain's typings not regenerated properly.